How can I simulate the diffraction limit for the Fresnel diffraction equation?
If I propagate a field using the Fresnel diffraction equation and then propagate back again, I can resolve the original image that I started with.
But as I understand, in reality, I should be limited in what I can resolve due to the diffraction limit, which depends on the wavelength.
I'd expect to be able to start with a high resolution image that represents the original object, including details that are beyond the diffraction limit. Propagate it to simulate the effect of Fresnel diffraction, and then find I can only retrieve a lower resolution than the original true object.
def fresnel_diffraction(amplitudes, wavelength_m, z_distance_m, kx, ky):
    """
    Simulates Fresnel diffraction of a wavefront.

    Parameters:
    amplitudes (numpy array): The amplitude of the wavefront.
    wavelength_m (float): The wavelength of the light in meters.
    z_distance_m (float): The propagation distance in meters.
    kx (numpy array): The fractional angles in the x direction.
    ky (numpy array): The fractional angles in the y direction.

    Returns:
    numpy array: The resulting field after propagation.
    """
    # Calculate the transfer function in the frequency domain
    transfer_function = np.exp(-1j * np.pi * wavelength_m * z_distance_m * (kx**2 + ky**2))

    # Shift the transfer function for the Fourier transform
    transfer_function = np.fft.fftshift(transfer_function)

    # Compute the Fourier transform of the input amplitudes
    amplitude_ft = np.fft.fft2(amplitudes)

    # Multiply the Fourier-transformed amplitudes by the transfer function
    field_ft = amplitude_ft * transfer_function

    # Compute the inverse Fourier transform to get the propagated field
    propagated_field = np.fft.ifft2(field_ft)

    return propagated_field
```


The loss of resolution that you get in physical optical systems is a result of filtering introduced by the system. One can represent such a filtering process with an aperture on the frequency domain. In other words, compute the angular spectrum and multiply it with an aperture functions which is equal to 1 within a certain radius and zero outside. When you perform an inverse Fourier transform on this result, it will produce a field with lower resolution.

What I'm trying to do is simulate the natural diffraction limit due to the wavelength of the light. If I just add a filter, am I not just picking an arbitrary resolution by picking the filter radius, rather than it being related to the wavelength?

Then the "aperture" you need has a radius equal to the wavenumber of the light. It excludes all the evanescent waves and only allows the propagating waves through. I've done this to study the amplitude of an optical vortex in an old paper of mine: Optics Communications 223, 31–37 (2003). Unfortunately it is behind a pay-wall but perhaps you have access to it.
